# Need Application Advice

Tags: django, graphics, newsletter

I have a django application that contains customer and product information.   It is simple but gets the job done.  My customer wants the capability to send form letters and news letters and create them from within my app.   From a text editing perspective, I understand how simple form letters  work by replacing certain blocks of text with queries from the database.  But my customer wants fliers with complex graphics and column-based layouts.     There are some very mature products out there that I can't come close (nor want to) compete with.   He talked about building and editing these pages from within my app.  This seems a bridge too far but I don't know if its even possible to build that into a django app.

I have no idea how to approach this and it seems very complicated.   But, before say no, I want to explore the available technology and level of effort entailed.   Are there open source packages that can help?  How could one integrate this capability into a django-based web application?  and how hard is it?  For a part-time intermediate developer how long would it take?

Answer (score 0):

I'd farm the layout off to something like [TeX Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live). From there you can generate a PDF and attach it to an email message. Don't let "... a popular means by which to typeset complex mathematical formulae" throw you, TeX is useful for more than that.

Comment: Interesting....  Are you aware of any examples that embed TeX or TeX editing into a web environment?

Comment: Only [mathTeX](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html) myself, but I'm sure there's others.